# Prolog output should match the input of the sat solver

Tags: prolog, logic, swi-prolog, sat

Another user created a very useful code for me, which i will be using to create random k-cnf formulas. I found a good sat-solver online which i want to use to check the satisfiability of the k-cnf formula. There is a problem though. The output is different from the sat-solver its input, i would like this to match, in order for me to feed the random generated k-cnf formulas to the sat solver.

Code for the k-cnf generator

```
     random_knowledge_base(NumberOfClauses,
                      LiteralsPerClause,
                      AmountOfLiterals,
                      Ratio,
                      KnowledgeBase) :-
    length(KnowledgeBase, NumberOfClauses),
    maplist(random_clause(LiteralsPerClause, AmountOfLiterals, Ratio), KnowledgeBase).


random_clause(LiteralsPerClause, AmountOfLiterals, Ratio, Head :- Body) :-
    randseq(LiteralsPerClause, AmountOfLiterals, [Number|Numbers]), 
    atom_concat(p, Number, Head),  
    maplist(literal(Ratio), Numbers, Literals), 
    comma_list(Body, Literals). 


literal(Ratio, Number, Literal) :- 
    atom_concat(p, Number, Proposition)
    (   maybe(Ratio)  
    ->  Literal = Proposition 
    ;   Literal = -Proposition ).
```

The predicate `comma_list/2` can be used to transform a list of literals into a conjunction:

For example

```
?- randseq(3, 5, Ns), maplist(literal(0.5), Ns, Ls), comma_list(B, Ls).

Ns = [1, 5, 3],

Ls = [p1, p5, p3],

B =  (p1, p5, p3).
```

when querying

```
?- random_knowledge_base(4, 3, 5, 0.5, KB).
```

The output

```
KB = [(p1, -p4, -p5),  (p2, p3, p4),  (p2, p3, -p5),  (p3, -p1, -p4)].
```

But i want the output to stay int the "Ls" form, meaning that it would look like this

```
KB = [[p1, -p4, -p5],  [p2, p3, p4],  [p2, p3, -p5],  [p3, -p1, -p4]].
```

Because eventually, i want the output to look like this, to match this input of the sat solver:

```
?- sat([[true-X,false-Y],[false-X,false-Y],[true-X,true-Z]],[X,Y,Z]).
```

where The solver is called with two arguments. The first represents a formula in CNF
as a list of lists, each constituent list representing a clause. The literals of a
clause are represented as pairs, Pol-Var, where Var is a logical variable and Pol
is true or false, indicating that the literal has positive or negative polarity. The
formula `¬x∨(y ∧ ¬z)` would thus be represented in CNF as `(¬x∨y)∧(¬x∨ ¬z)`
and presented to the solver as the list

```
L = [[false-X, true-Y], [false-X,
false-Z]]
```

where X, Y and Z are logical variables. The second argument is a list
of the variables occurring in the problem. Thus the query `sat(L, [X, Y, Z])`
will succeed and bind the variables to a solution, for example,

```
X = false, Y
= true, Z = true.
```

As a by-product, L will be instantiated to

```
[[false-false,
true-true], [false-false, false-true]].
```

This illustrates that the interpretation of true and false in L depends on whether they are left or right of the - operator: to the left they denote polarity; to the right, they denote truth values. If L is unsatisfiable then `sat(L, Vars)` will fail. If necessary, the solver can be called under a double negation to check for satisfiability, whilst leaving the variables unbound.

Code for checking satisfiability

```
sat(Clauses, Vars) :-
     problem_setup(Clauses), elim_var(Vars).

elim_var([]).
elim_var([Var | Vars]) :-
     elim_var(Vars), (Var = true; Var = false).

problem_setup([]).
problem_setup([Clause | Clauses]) :-
     clause_setup(Clause),
     problem_setup(Clauses).

clause_setup([Pol-Var | Pairs]) :- set_watch(Pairs, Var, Pol).

set_watch([], Var, Pol) :- Var = Pol.
set_watch([Pol2-Var2 | Pairs], Var1, Pol1):-
     watch(Var1, Pol1, Var2, Pol2, Pairs).

:- block watch(-, ?, -, ?, ?).
watch(Var1, Pol1, Var2, Pol2, Pairs) :-
     nonvar(Var1) ->
        update_watch(Var1, Pol1, Var2, Pol2, Pairs);
        update_watch(Var2, Pol2, Var1, Pol1, Pairs).

update_watch(Var1, Pol1, Var2, Pol2, Pairs) :-
        Var1 == Pol1 -> true; set_watch(Pairs, Var2, Pol2).
```

Anyone that could help would be my hero :)
credits to @slago

ps if the output has to be restricted to a certain K, i.e. 3-cnf, to fit the sat solver, that would also be fine

Comment: @slago, here it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code must be altered as follows:

```
random_knowledge_base(NumberOfClauses,
                      LiteralsPerClause,
                      AmountOfLiterals,
                      Ratio,
                      KnowledgeBase,
                      Variables ) :-     % <== Add output argument to get used variables
    length(KnowledgeBase, NumberOfClauses),
    length(Variables, AmountOfLiterals), % <== Generate a set of variables to be used
    maplist(random_clause(LiteralsPerClause, AmountOfLiterals, Variables, Ratio), KnowledgeBase).

random_clause(LiteralsPerClause, AmountOfLiterals, Variables, Ratio, Literals) :-
    randseq(LiteralsPerClause, AmountOfLiterals, Numbers),
    maplist(literal(Ratio,Variables), Numbers, Literals).

literal(Ratio, Variables, Number, Literal) :-
    nth1(Number, Variables, Proposition), % <== Map each number into a corresponding variable
    (   maybe(Ratio)
    ->  Literal = true-Proposition
    ;   Literal = false-Proposition ).
```

Examples:

```
?- literal(0.5, [X,Y,Z], 1, Literal).
Literal = false-X.

?- literal(0.5, [X,Y,Z], 2, Literal).
Literal = true-Y.

?- random_clause(2, 3, [X,Y,Z], 0.5, C).
C = [false-X, true-Y].

?- random_clause(2, 3, [X,Y,Z], 0.5, C).
C = [true-Z, true-X].

?- random_knowledge_base(3, 2, 3, 0.5, K, V).
K = [[false-_A, false-_B], [false-_C, true-_A], [false-_B, false-_C]],
V = [_B, _A, _C].


?- random_knowledge_base(3, 2, 3, 0.5, K, V), sat(K, V).
K = [[false-true, true-true], [true-true, true-true], [true-true, true-true]],
V = [true, true, true] ;
K = [[false-false, true-true], [true-false, true-true], [true-true, true-false]],
V = [false, true, true] ;
K = [[false-true, true-true], [true-true, true-true], [true-false, true-true]],
V = [true, true, false] ;
false.
```

**EDIT** Use the following predicate to see the random knowledge base before the instatiations made by `sat/2`:

```
show(K, V) :-
    copy_term(K-V, Kn-Vn),
    numbervars(Kn-Vn),
    format('Knowledge base: ~w\n', [Kn]),
    format('Propositions..: ~w\n\n', [Vn]).
```

Example:

```
?- random_knowledge_base(3, 2, 3, 0.5, K, V), show(K, V), sat(K, V).
Knowledge base: [[false-A,true-B],[true-C,true-A],[false-A,false-C]]
Propositions..: [C,A,B]

K = [[false-true, true-true], [true-false, true-true], [false-true, false-false]],
V = [false, true, true] ;
K = [[false-false, true-true], [true-true, true-false], [false-false, false-true]],
V = [true, false, true] ;
K = [[false-false, true-false], [true-true, true-false], [false-false, false-true]],
V = [true, false, false] ;
false.
```

Comment: question, in the last query is K instantiated with the output of the query above ([[false-_A, false-_B], [false-_C, true-_A], [false-_B, false-_C]]) or is it a new knowledge base, i am not sure how to interpret that part. Thanks in advance

Comment: @AmaSma See **EDIT** in my answer (it would be nice if you could upvote it!)

Comment: thank you! but for some reason, i cannot upvote it, because I recently just been active on stackoverflow

Comment: is there a way, instead of printing a solution and the generated list it would just get true (satisfiable) because I'm measuring runtime for the program to find a solution or not (unsat) but printing the cnf formula and its solution takes up quite some time, let me know!